# Google Play Leaderboard integration

Tags: google-play-games

Is there a way to use GooglePlay Leaderboard showing a line of short text instead of Score?
I intend to rank players base on their acquired Title. The title is acquired through player's level. In short, I want to show the title instead of Score (as level). Is it possible to do that? Or it's not supported at the moment?